# Handling blank floats in XML from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Issue: When I run the below code the output for the XML, where the field that is a float, comes out as *0.000000000000000e+000* I would like it to be blank or because it's XML to not appear at all.

Thoughts: I tried   `COALESCE(c.ProductType,'')` as well as   `COALESCE(c.ProductType,'999')` I tried with 999 to see what happens, however in both cases `<ProductType>` is missed from the XML feed but the value *0.000000000000000e+000* is still returned.

Query: How to handle XML, created from SQL, where a Float is blank

Code: (Showing two shows rather than all)

```
USE DATABASE

    SELECT      
          e.UPRN       
          ,c.ProductType AS ProductType

            FROM TblTable e(NOLOCK)
      JOIN
      TblAsbestos c (NOLOCK)
      ON e.UPRN = c.UPRN  

      WHERE e.UPRN = 'SH1266'

    FOR XML PATH('XML_DATA') , ROOT ('SURVEYDATA')
```

XML Output:

```
<SURVEYDATA>
  <XML_DATA>
    <UPRN>SH1266</UPRN>
    <LocationItemPosition>This works</LocationItemPosition>
    <SurveyDate>2014-01-16T00:00:00</SurveyDate>
    <SurveyCompany></SurveyCompany>
    <ProductType>0.000000000000000e+000</ProductType>
   </XML_DATA>
</SURVEYDATA>
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone voted to close as I have been unable to find this on Stackoverflow. If there is a link to the answer that would be great.

Comment: A float can't be blank. It can be NULL or 0. If you convert an empty string to a float it will be converted to 0. As a side note, you are using deprecated syntax for query hints. The WITH keyword is no longer optional. In general query hints should be avoided unless you really know what you are doing and all other options have been exhausted. The NOLOCK hint is particularly nasty one. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I just noticed that your float is ProductType. Why are using a float for that anyway? Shouldn't that be an exact numeric instead of an approximate one? How many decimal places do you need for a ProductType??

Comment: ProductType is not what you would think, in this case, field names are factual names that make sense in report context, however I didn't want to give all  the fields here to focus on the issue, otherwise it would make sense.

Comment: I'll remove the nolock, it came from an example I used. (Seen it on quite a few but the link was really useful @SeanLange )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at this (tested on SQL Server 2012, should work from 2008)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(UPRN VARCHAR(100),ProductType FLOAT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('valid Float',123.45)
                      ,('Float is zero',0.0)
                      ,('Float is missing',NULL);
SELECT *
FROM @tbl AS tbl
FOR XML PATH('XML_DATA'),ROOT('SURVEYDATA');

/* Result
<SURVEYDATA>
  <XML_DATA>
    <UPRN>valid Float</UPRN>
    <ProductType>1.234500000000000e+002</ProductType>
  </XML_DATA>
  <XML_DATA>
    <UPRN>Float is zero</UPRN>
    <ProductType>0.000000000000000e+000</ProductType>
  </XML_DATA>
  <XML_DATA>
    <UPRN>Float is missing</UPRN>
  </XML_DATA>
</SURVEYDATA>
*/

SELECT tbl.UPRN 
      ,CAST(tbl.ProductType AS DECIMAL(12,4)) AS ProductType
FROM @tbl AS tbl
FOR XML PATH('XML_DATA'),ROOT('SURVEYDATA');

/* Result with "nicer" numbers, but the empty one is missing...
<SURVEYDATA>
  <XML_DATA>
    <UPRN>valid Float</UPRN>
    <ProductType>123.4500</ProductType>
  </XML_DATA>
  <XML_DATA>
    <UPRN>Float is zero</UPRN>
    <ProductType>0.0000</ProductType>
  </XML_DATA>
  <XML_DATA>
    <UPRN>Float is missing</UPRN>
  </XML_DATA>
</SURVEYDATA>
*/

SELECT tbl.UPRN 
      ,CAST(tbl.ProductType AS DECIMAL(12,4)) AS ProductType,'' AS ProductType
FROM @tbl AS tbl
FOR XML PATH('XML_DATA'),ROOT('SURVEYDATA');

/* Result, "nicer" numbers and the empty one appears as empty tag.
The trick: There are two elements with the same name and they are concatenated implicitly... 
Nothing plus an empty string is: the empty string!
<SURVEYDATA>
  <XML_DATA>
    <UPRN>valid Float</UPRN>
    <ProductType>123.4500</ProductType>
  </XML_DATA>
  <XML_DATA>
    <UPRN>Float is zero</UPRN>
    <ProductType>0.0000</ProductType>
  </XML_DATA>
  <XML_DATA>
    <UPRN>Float is missing</UPRN>
    <ProductType></ProductType>
  </XML_DATA>
</SURVEYDATA>
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177562.aspx) around c.ProductType should do the trick.

```
DECLARE @f FLOAT; SET @f = 0

SELECT      
   'SH1266' as UPRN,
   NULLIF(@f, 0.0) AS ProductType
FOR XML PATH('XML_DATA') , ROOT ('SURVEYDATA')
```

As Sean Lange commented above though, float is an unusual data type for a column called ProductType.